# Fade in and fade out overlay by toggling a hamburger menu

Tags: jquery, css

So there's a website I'm working on which uses a hamburger menu. Once is clicked, this hamburger menu shows a a fullscreen overlay with menu options.

I would like this overlay to fade in when the hamburger menu is clicked and fade out once it's clicked again.

At the moment I have being able to make the overlay to fade in by adding an active class to the overlay menu and by adding the following CSS:

```
.overlay {

  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s, visibility 1s;
  transition: opacity 1s, visibility 1s;

}

.overlay.open {

visibility: visible;
opacity: 1;
z-index: 50;

}
```

However, I have no clue how I could make the overlay to fade out when the toggle is clicked once again.

Here's the development site if you guys want to check a working example:

http://dev.alvaroching.com/

Thanks!

Comment: You didn't include this in your code, but on the website I'm noticing a `z-index` property required to see the nav overlay only appearing on `.overlay.open`. Move this `z-index` to your main `.overlay` class and everything should work.

Comment: Try the [CSS3 transition-timing-function Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition-timing-function.asp)

Comment: @ShengSlogar Hi Chen, this is spot on the correct answer. I had no idea this was causing the problem. I'll edit the question so you can add the answer! It would be cool to know why the z-index was the cause of the problem too. Thanks!

Comment: @Johann Glad that worked out for you! You didn't have to make an edit, but I'll totally copy this into an answer so you can mark this as resolved. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `z-index` property isn't animatable, and is therefore required on both the open and unopened nav overlay for other animations to be seen. (It's comparable to setting an element to `display: none` and wondering why animations aren't visible.)

Moving the `z-index` from the `.overlay.open` class to the main `.overlay` class solves this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a delay to your `visibility` change, when it's changing to `hidden`, otherwise it'll disappear before the animation completes:

```
.overlay{
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s, visibility 0s 1s;
}

.overlay.open{
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ilpo/wzwrwsdm/

Answer (score 1):

Replace `transition: opacity 1s, visibility 1s;` in the overlay class with `transition: all 1s;`

Answer (score 0):

use this jquery code to make that fadein / fadeout effect

```
 var x=true;
    $('.button_container').click(function(){
    if(x){
    $('.overlay').fadeOut(1000);x=false;}
    else{
    $('.overlay').fadeIn(1000);x=true;}

    });
```